# How to remove subpaths from a CGPath?

Tags: objective-c, ios

A few subpaths are added to  a mutable graphics path:

```
 CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, subpath1);
 // ...
 CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, subpath2);
 // ...
 CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, subpath3);
```

How can I remove some/all subpaths from `path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you are responsable to keep the data required to redraw the path (or part of it) if needed (you basically have to create a new path containing only the subpaths you want to keep).

Comment: You could also visit the elements of the path using `CGPathApply`, and add the ones you want to keep to a new path.  But you'd have to be able to identify which elements of the old path you want to keep (or remove)…

Comment: Using CGPathApply complicates things because the callback gives you a point and the drawing type that occur to that point. Is true that you can redraw parts of the path using this info, but you have to keep more data about your subpaths, both their points and the drawing operations they were made with. This is because a subpath can potentially be made with more than one drawing operation.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up storing paths in a `NSMutableArray`.